# Change the wrap priority between parent and child

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a page like this

```
+---------+-------------------+
|         | +-------+-------+ |
|    A    | |  B    |   C   | |
|         | +---------------+ |
+---------+-------------------+
```

The main and sub containers are declared as flex wrapping elements

```css
.main{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main .sub{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

When the page get smaller the main element wrap before the sub element

```
+-------------------+
|                   |
|         A         |
|                   | 
+-------------------+
| +-------+-------+ |
| |  B    |   C   | |
| +---------------+ |
+-------------------+
```

But I would like the sub element to wrap before the main to get

```
+-------------------+----------+
|                   | +------+ |
|                   | |  B   | |
|         A         | +------+ |
|                   | |  C   | |
|                   | +------+ |
+-------------------+----------+
```

I would like to change this behaviours to give the wrapping priority to the sub element.

Comment: share your html code

Comment: So the b and c element would go down after A when resized more?

Comment: @ManojKumar Yes that the idea

Answer (score 1):

You could achive this behaviour by setting `flex-wrap: wrap` and a `flex-basis` (test the snippet as a full-page).

```css
div {
   outline: 1px #ccc  dashed;
   padding: 20px;
   flex: 1 1 200px;
}

div.sub {
   flex-basis: 75px;
}



.flex {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<main class="flex">

   <div>A</div>

   <div class="flex sub">
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
   </div>

</main>
```